# Find form input without jquery

Tags: javascript, forms, input

Hi I want to get a string from a form. I am a new to javascript.
In console.log(value) the value is value. Why? I want it to be the value from 
my form. Thank you! :)

```js
let value = document.getElementById("password").value;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: Could it be that you're doing `console.log("value")` instead of `console.log(value)`?

Comment: It says undefined with ```console.log(value)```

Comment: Does is log `undefined` or return `undefined`? Try `alert` instead of `console.log`?

Comment: can u use codesnippet and give us the example code

Comment: Im sorry it logged nothing, it is just one empty line. Same answer with ```alert``` empty window.

Comment: This is html ```<form>
 <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" />
</form>
``` i want to enter a string and take that value in javascript then output it on the website

Comment: Do you include the javascript under the elements in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and play with this to get the string when it is changed:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
// Here myString is declared outside event listener so it can be used to store data.
let myString = "";

// This will be executed only on input changes.
document.getElementById("password").addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  // Store string value
  myString  = event.srcElement.value;

  // this will log string value
  console.log(myString);
  // or
  logPassword();

  // output value in another html tag
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myString;
});

// This will log empty string because myString = ""
// This code is executed at start like it is
console.log(myString);

// An example of function that can be create to access myString
function logPassword() {
  console.log(myString);
}
```

[Mozilla input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

**EDIT**: Solution using button

Note: you don't need form tag if you don't submit something.

- Solution 1:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" />
  <!-- Pass the input password value to the write function -->
  <button onclick="writeText(document.getElemenById('password').value)" id="bocken">ok.</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
// Pass the string (submitted password) 
function writeText(myString){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myString;
}
```

For a better use of javascript by waiting the DOM is ready

```js
// All code inside will be executed only when the page is loaded and ready to use.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // do work 
  function writeText(myString){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myString;
  }
});
```

- Solution 2:

```html
<input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" />
<button id="bocken">ok.</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
// All code inside will be executed only when the page is loaded and ready to use.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // This will be executed only on button click event.
  document.getElementById("bocken").addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // output value in another html tag
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElemenById('password').value;
  });
});
```

Comment: Howe do i output the input in my website?

Comment: is the value saved inside myString?  ```document.getElementById(result).innerHTML = myString ``` did not work

Comment: Put a value in your html and see what you have. In the way you write the code, the log will always be the same, empty string, because the value is empty. It's why you have to create an event listener to check if there is new data and do what you what with it, but in the event.

Comment: How do i get it to print when button is pressed? i tried ```     <button onclick="writeText(password)" id="bocken">ok.</button> ```   .and i put this inside a function ```  function writeText(){

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myString;

}```  . i want myString to execute when pressed ok.